# Audio cassette to MP3 or CD

Tags: windows, audio, media-converter

I have plenty of old audio cassettes. I want the songs of the cassette in MP3 or some other computer playable format.

Is there any software available for converting audio cassettes to MP3 or CD?

Comment: Where you would plug the audio cassette at first place?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Windows, Linux, MacOS?

Comment: Using Tape Recorder. I Connect Tape Recorder and Cpu with Audio cable.

Comment: @frlan : Windows 7

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I used to do this. Most cassette player have an audio output jack plug. Just put a male-to-male audio cable from that to your computer's microphone input jack plug.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul that's amazing, I had cassettes, but didn't had computer, now I am having on, but no cassettes to test with :)

Comment: If you care about quality, I would suggest getting an external shielded soundcard.  It will almost completely eliminate any "hum" that will naturally be introduced via your computer's electronics through your average internal soundcard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).

Features:

- Free, open-source and multiplatform software.
- Includes processing options for removing noise, and normalising volume.
- Can detect silence between tracks to help with conversion.
- There is a tutorial for doing precisely what you want: http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/tutorial_copying_tapes_lps_or_minidiscs_to_cd.html

If you save as MP3 you need to download LAME encoder from [here](http://lame.buanzo.org/#lamewindl).

Answer (score 1):

I connect my cassette player or my vinyl player to a [Behringer UFO202](http://www.behringer.com/EN/Products/UFO202.aspx). This connects via USB cable to my Windows PC. On Windows I run [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/). I set the input levels appropriately - the main thing is just to make sure there is no "clipping". This setup works very well. Audacity can record to mp3 or other formats. The audio quality is very good - or at least good enough for me!

The main annoyance with this is that I need to record each track one at a time, pausing the cassette player after each track.

The other thing you will need to do is manually set the audio "meta data' for each track - the artist name, track #, track name, album name, etc. Audacity prompts you to do this when you export the track to mp3, or you can also use software like [VLC player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) to do it after the mp3 has been created.

Comment: There is a function in Audacity that allows you to split a track (it's called "Export", but it just splits the track) at markers that you create.  So, you can record the entire cassette in one shot and then go back and mark where the tracks begin and export them into separate tracks.

Comment: @JohnnyBones. Good to know. I'll try this out next time.